# readFile async await in nodejs

Tags: node.js, promise, request, fs

```js
import http from "http"
import fs from "fs"

function readDemo(path){
    return new Promise((resolve,reject)=>{
        fs.readFile(path,(err,data)=>{
            if(err)
                reject(err);
            else
                resolve(data);
        })
    })
}

const server = http.createServer((req,res)=>{
    if(req.url === `/`){
        res.writeHead(200,{"Content-type":"text/html"});
        readDemo(`./todo.html`)//
            .then(data => res.write(data))
            .catch(console.log);
        res.end();
    }
})

server.listen(5000);
```

I'm trying to load `todo.html` by requesting `localhost:5000` as running my own server in Nodejs
It seems fs.readFile took long time to load css and javascript section so I made Promise statement to make `res.write` waiting for `fs.readFile` to finish load `todo.html` include css and javascript linked in it.

However code set err says

```
events.js:292
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error [ERR_STREAM_WRITE_AFTER_END]: write after end
    at writeAfterEnd (_http_outgoing.js:668:15)
    at write_ (_http_outgoing.js:680:5)
    at ServerResponse.write (_http_outgoing.js:661:15)
    at file:///C:/Users/KUSW-14/Downloads/web_study-main/web_study-main/to_do_list/main.js:19:31   
Emitted 'error' event on ServerResponse instance at:
    at writeAfterEndNT (_http_outgoing.js:727:7)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:81:21) {
  code: 'ERR_STREAM_WRITE_AFTER_END'
}
```

Can anyone help me what's wrong with my code?

Comment: fyi [`fs.promises.readFile`](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fspromises_readfile_path_options)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `readFile()` is non-blocking so you're calling `res.end()` BEFORE you call `res.write()`.   I'd suggest using `await` like this:

```
const server = http.createServer(async (req, res) => {
    if(req.url === `/`){
        try {
            const data = await readDemo(`./todo.html`);
            res.writeHead(200,{"Content-type":"text/html"});
            res.write(data)
            res.end();
        } catch(e) {
            console.log(e);
            res.writeHead(500);
            res.end();
        }
    } else {
        res.writeHead(404);
        res.end();
    }
});
```

Without `await`, you need to move the `res.end()` inside of the `.then()`:

```
const server = http.createServer((req,res)=>{
    if(req.url === `/`){
        readDemo(`./todo.html`).then(data => {
            res.writeHead(200,{"Content-type":"text/html"});
            res.write(data);
            res.end();
        }).catch(err => {
            console.log(err);
            res.writeHead(500);
            res.end();
        });
    } else {
        res.writeHead(404);
        res.end();
    }
});
```

FYI, in modern versions of node.js `fs.promises.readFile()` is already a promise version so you don't have to make your own.